# pie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Running the following code:

```
plt.pie(data=df['rating'].value_counts(), labels= df['rating'], autopct='%.1f%%')
plt.show()
```

Returns this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-13b4cf180db8> in <module>
----> 1 plt.pie(data=df['rating'].value_counts(), labels= df['rating'], autopct='%.1f%%')
      2 plt.show()

TypeError: pie() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

As shown in this picture:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should give you what you want.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['rating'].value_counts().reset_index())

plt.pie(data=df1,x='rating',labels='index', autopct='%.1f%%')
```